# how to parse xml which contains special characters in element attribute value .how to replace that special character with space and parse it in java

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, xml-serialization

am trying to parse a xml file in java using DOM OR SAX. the problem is while parsing , if my xml contains atteibute values as special character like < > " then parser throws ParserException.

for example xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<abc>
<check name="bike" value="apache <nice model"/> 
<check name="car" value="tata sumo "style" />
</abc>
```

in this example xml element check has attribute value and it contains < or " . the parser takes it as invalid and throws parser exception.

now my problem is ,before parsing xml file to parser , detect that special character(< or > or " ) in xml file attribute values and have to replace that symbol(< > ") with spaces.

eg: if xml contains <

```
<check name="bike" value="apache <nice model"/>
```

replace with space

```
<check name="bike" value="apache  nice model"/>
```

.please give me suggestions.in what method it can be done...can we do it using XSD...

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing those symbols with entities?

```
&apos; is an apostrophe: '
&amp; is an ampersand: &
&quot; is a quotation mark: "
&lt; is a less-than symbol: <
&gt; is a greater-than symbol: >
```

Comment: but i have no idea about how to replace only the attribute value < as &lt;     being new to xml,i dono how to replace only the attribute value like 'apache <nice model' as 'apache &lt nice model' .

Answer (score 0):

One could argue if it really is xml. One rule is that xml must be well-formed. That means tags must have opening and closing, certain characters are not allowed (particularly <> in attributes) in all places.

If you can't correct this from the source, that is, produce well-formed xml, then I guess you need to first do simple search and replace as @Visher suggests and then treat it as xml or come up with your own parser

Answer (score 0):

This code works pretty well (replaces '<' and '>' in quotation marks):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[] characters = new char[]{'<', '>'};
    String[] entities = new String[]{"&lt;", "&gt;"};

    String text = "<check name=\"bike\" value=\"apache <nice model\"/> ";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean insideQuotation = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++)
    {
        char character = text.charAt(i);

        if (insideQuotation)
        {
            int index = -1;

            for (int x = 0; x < characters.length; x++)
            {
                if (characters[x] == character)
                {
                    index = x;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (index != -1)
                sb.append(entities[index]);

            else
                sb.append(character);

            if (character == '"')
                insideQuotation = false; 
        }
        else
        {
            if (character == '"')
                insideQuotation = true;

            sb.append(character);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

There will be a problem if you will add another quotations marks inside quotation.

Comment: really i m thankfull to u:)thanks for putting such a effort:)

Comment: if we pass a xml file and convert into string.and if we follow the same method ..whether it will work ah??